# How to make a geometry_msgs/PoseArray and then visualise it using rviz?

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say I need to run Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest distance between two points.

Can anyone tell me how to make a pose array and use it to store the shortest path and then visualise it?

[image: What I've done so far]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337174/how-to-make-a-geometry_msgs/posearray-and-then-visualise-it-using-rviz?/) by [Parth2851](https://answers.ros.org/users/48975/parth2851/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2019-11-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-11-08**:
If you construct a `PoseArray` message in your Dijkstra node and publish it, then there is a built-in Display type in rviz to visualize this data. Might I suggest you edit your question and be a bit more specific about what part of this process you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way to do this is using the nav_msgs/path message already available on ROS

http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html

It consists on an array of PoseStamped with a common header..

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2019-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-11-08**:
Plus the `nav_msgs/Path` it has a built-in display in `rviz`.